# Why can I input an alphabet "e" when the input type is number

Tags: nuxt.js

I accidentally tried to type "e" and it is recorded in the input field.

```
  <input type="number" v-model="value"/>
```

But other letters are not recorded

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the rest of the code?

Comment: Probably because `1.2e3` is a valid number (haven't checked)?

Comment: Actually, even if I remove the rest of the code, using that alone still generates the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to force some number value from your input.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    value >> {{ inputField }}
    <input v-model.number="inputField" type="number" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      inputField: null,
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

This code will not show anything if something else that a number is typed.

More details on the `.number` modifier in the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#number).

Comment: am I right to say that it is a bug in the input type="value"?

Comment: This is not a _bug_,  more the way of how HTML works. Btw, there are only strings in HTML, so even `123` is actually `"123"` in the HTML. But it can be `123` in Vue's state!